# Blender wont find python in usr/local/bin

Tags: python, error

I wont to run blender2.49 and I have compiled and installed python 2.6.6 under /usr/local/bin and when I start blender in console it says

```
Compiled with Python version 2.6.2.
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

when I run python in console it says python 2.6.6
How can I add python to library path or $pytonhome ?

Comment: Are you on mac or on linux?

Comment: Im on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: No need to compile or install, there are ready to use self-contained versions in the release archive https://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, open a terminal session.
In your user directory (e.g. `mac/users/doeke`) make sure you have a file named `.bash_profile` If it is not there then create one.

Open terminal.

`sudo nano .bash_profile`

add:

`export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/bin/python_whatever_the_fing_path_is`

press `ctrl + x` to quit and hit `y` to save the file.

Now log in and out or reboot. Hopefully it is fixed now.